# testing session variables and db storage in cherrypy app

Tags: python, unit-testing, cherrypy

I'm looking to write some unit tests for some cherrypy code.

Most of the unit test examples I have seen depend on os.environ and generally only test for the final response (html output) from the cherrypy apps.

I'm looking for:

- testing that session variables have been set/unset for a given request (e.g., user logs in, I want to verify that his 'user' session variable is correct as well as his login time, etc...
- checking values in a datastore (mysql/mongodb)
- running tests in parallel. By default you access session and other information from cherrypy.cookie/cherrypy.session, etc... These are basically global. Is it possible to access this information another way?

Any other recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small python http client and (assuming you run your server) unittest the responses.

Some libs that might be useful:

- [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html)
- [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)
- [http.client](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.client.html)

Also you might want to check out [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) (allows you to script your browser in python for test cases).